# NHibernate property formula filter

Tags: nhibernate, hibernate

I have a following class:

```
MyClass
public virtual int Id { get; set; }
public virtual int Code { get; set; }
public virtual int Description { get; set; }
public virtual int Name { get; set; }
```

with the following mapping:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" namespace="TestApplication" assembly="TestApplication">
  <class name="MyClass" table="MyTable">
    <id name="Id" column="id">
      <generator class="native"/>
    </id>

    <property name="Code" column="code"/>
    <property name="Description" column="description"/>
    <property name="Name" formula="(SELECT b.translation FROM translations b WHERE b.translation_id = translation_id AND b.language_id = :TranslationFilter.LanguageId)"/>
  </class>

  <filter-def name="TranslationFilter">
    <filter-param name="LanguageId" type="Int32"/>
  </filter-def>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

I'm trying to load entity through spring with:

```
Session.EnableFilter("TranslationFilter").SetParameter("LanguageId", 1);
return Session.Get<MyClass>(1);
```

but I'am getting adoexception. I see (in a profiler) that variable :TranslationFilter.LanguageId is not replaced with ? and that parameter value is not send to the server?

Is it this possible (to have filters in formula) and how?

Many thanks!

Comment: This should be possible, Oren gives an example on his blog: http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2006/12/26/LocalizingNHibernateContextualParameters.aspx

Comment: :) I read this blog post several times (before posting here), to see where I am wrong, but I couldn't see the difference. But it is interesting that someone on nhforge said that parameters in formulas are not supported...

Answer (score 1):

This feature is not officially supported. As such oren's blog post about this combination of 2 different features (formulas and filters) should be taken with a grain of salt...

Comment: This `feature` is exactly what i was searching for. After database changes a column that was used in a formula did not exist anymore and using a new view or query is not an option. Since we are using our own generic framework to build dynamic `Criteria` based on generic filters from remote UI web-tier we want to keep it generic. Our application is so big, if we need to write a custom Query at app-tier for every single filter property our code would get unmanageble or costs would explode. At web-tier it is a one line change to activate the filter.