# nHibernate/Fluent - SQL Query Question

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I am new to nHibernate. I understand how to use mapping using Fluent nHibernate. Now I would like to use a little more complex query. However I am not sure how I would map or even approach this. Here is what I would like to do in an sql query:

```
SELET 
  Zone,
  CountOfStyles = (Select Count(1) from anotherTable Where StoreZoneId = zone.ZoneID),
  ZoneId,
  ZoneTitle,
  ZoneDescription
FROM
  Zones
```

How would I map this using fluent nHibernate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this might get you started...

UPDATE:

**mapping**

```
Map(x => x.CountOfStyles).Formula("(Select Count(1) from anotherTable Where StoreZoneId = ZoneID)");
```

Comment: he wants the count to be part of the query for the entity, not to eager load the list of styles just to get the count.

Comment: I could do that, but the whole idea to use nhibernate was to get away from views/sprocs. There is no other way? My query is not really complex :)

Comment: Just found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/887474/nhibernate-property-formula-filter

Comment: And more here... 

http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2006/12/26/LocalizingNHibernateContextualParameters.aspx

Comment: I got it working. Since both of my fields are called the same in both tables, I did not know exactly how to use the parent field. I just had to add the anotherTable into the where clause. 

Map(x => x.CountOfStyles).Formula("(Select Count(1) from anotherTable Where anotherTable.StoreZoneId = ZoneID)");