# Use SQL query to populate property in nHibernate mapping file

Tags: nhibernate

I have an object which contains a property that is the result of an SQL statement.  How do I add the SQL statement to my nHibernate mapping file?

Example Object:

```
public class Library{
    public int BookCount
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

Example Mapping File:

```
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="Library" table="Libraries">
        <property name="BookCount" type="int">  <- This is where I want the SQL query to populate the value. ->
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Example SQL Query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM BOOKS WHERE BOOKS.LIBRARY_ID = LIBRARIES.ID
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is discussed in [Ayende's blog post](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2009/04/07/nhibernate-mapping-ltpropertygt.aspx):

> formula is a way to specify any arbitrary SQL that we want to associate with a property. Obviously, this is a read only value, and it is something that we would use on fairly rare occasions. Nevertheless, it can be pretty useful at times.

Example:

```
<property name="BookCount" type="int" formula="(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM BOOKS WHERE BOOKS.LIBRARY_ID = ID)" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `formula` attribute on your property.

See here for an example: [NHibernate property formula filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/887474/nhibernate-property-formula-filter)