# NHibernate Map default item from a collection

Tags: nhibernate, dictionary

Lets say  I have a class Foo like the following:

```
public class Foo
{
    public virtual int FooId { get; protected internal set; }
    public virtual List<Bar> bars { get; protected internal set;}
    public virtual Bar DefaultBar { get; set; }
}
```

Where Foo has a collection of Bar and has a property DefaultBar of type Bar.

The collection of bars is stored in a table with the following fields

```
FooBarID   int   PK
FooID      int   FK
BarID      int   FK
Default    bit
```

Where only one row for a collection of matching FooID values can have a Default=1.  Ignoring this poor design (needed by legacy system),

In my map I have the following:

```
<class name="Bar">
  <id name="BarID" generator="native" unsaved-value="0" />
</class>

<class name="Foo">
  <id name="FooID" generator="native" unsaved-value="0" />
  <set name="Bars"
       table="FooBars">
    <key column="FooId" />
    <many-to-many class="Bar" column="BarId" />
  </set>

</class>
```

How would I map the value indicated by BarID in the single matching row with Default=1 to the DefaultBar property of the Foo instance?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose configuring the "formula" for your property can help you. See [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/887474/nhibernate-property-formula-filter).

Comment: Back to this now.

Your suggestion works for reading the default item, but not for setting the default.  Any other suggestions?

Comment: What do you mean "setting the default"? You just save an entity with a collection of Bars and one of this collection items has Default property set to true. That's it. The DefaultBar property with formula will be read only, otherwise it's something like a conflict - should the default bar be a part of collection or not and why etc... And if my answer helped you, you can mark it :)